# Get ClassNames acroos Java Projects

Tags: java

I need to develop a Tool for checking certain Java Code conventions for all the java classes present in a Java Project.
For one of the rules(i.e;Checking the Class Name Convention)I need to get all the Class Names given the Folder Name.Instead of parsing it line by line,can anybody suggest me a better way to do the same.

NOTE 1: Reflection is not an option because it doesn't work across java projects.I can not use build path as well since there would be many projects at run time for which i need to check the code conventions.

NOTE 2: Currently,I ma using eclipse IDE to build this,but in run time I am not even sure whether they would be using only eclipse IDE.Hence,when you suggest any eclipse plugin ,please bear this in mind.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Consider SonarQube or similar.  You should be able to add your own rules to these existing frameworks.  However, the class naming convention rule mentioned in the post sounds like a code review item (involving people) instead of code analysis.  How would a rule know the purpose of the class to determine if it has a good name?

Comment: This sounds like something that should rather be integrated into the build server instead of having a standalone tool somewhere on a developer PC that checks the Java class files for a manually selected folder on his local hard drive. But to give more advice it would be good to have more background how this tool should be used.

Comment: @FlorianS..This tool would be used to check in my office whether all the classes are following the coding conventions in different projects.There would be many java projects, and in each project there would be many packages,and each package could contain many classes.My Tool which would be written in certain JavaProject should be able to check for all the classes in other java projects as well.Hope you understood the requirement.

Comment: @AndrewS....I am aware of SonarQube. However, I am trying to write a tool for certain conditions which are not done by these tools.The class naming convention should check only the convention and not the meaning of the names.Here my rule is written to check only whether the Class name is following UpperCamel Case or not.That's all:)